# Tensorflow's Estimator stops training

Tags: tensorflow

I am training a model using Tensorflow's `Estimator` and it suddenly stops training after 2600 steps after performing an evaluation. Isn't it supposed to continue training until the end of the last epoch?

```
def train():
    train_input_func = lambda: input_fn(mode='train')
    eval_input_func = lambda: input_fn(mode='eval')

    est_conf = tf.estimator.RunConfig(cfg.model_dir, save_checkpoints_secs=120)
    estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn, cfg.model_dir, est_conf)


    Path(estimator.eval_dir()).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_input_func)
    eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=eval_input_func, throttle_secs=120)
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train()
```

And this is the `input_fn` function:

```
def input_fn(mode=None):
        data_generator = lambda: data_loader.data_generator(mode=mode)

        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator,
                                                 output_types=(tf.int32, tf.int32),
                                                 output_shapes=([None], [None]))

        if mode is 'train':
            dataset.shuffle(cfg.shuffle_buffer).repeat(1000)

        dataset = dataset.padded_batch(cfg.batch_size, padded_shapes=([None],[None])).prefetch(1)

        return dataset
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I did not assign `dataset.shuffle(cfg.shuffle_buffer).repeat(1000)`. This will fix the problem:

```
dataset = dataset.shuffle(cfg.shuffle_buffer).repeat(1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

When use `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate`, to make `max_steps` work, you should not use `repeat(1000)`, please use `repeat()`, it will repeat the input indefinitely, and will not throw `OutOfRangeError`.

Answer (score 0):

**First** You need to specify the max_stps in the TrainSpec definition like the following:

```py
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_input_func, max_steps=num_steps_you_specify)
```

**Second**
The training procedure will stop when the input_fn throws "OutOfRangeError" on which case the max_step will not work as it was designed to.  So in order to make the training run through the whole epochs, you need to specify the input_fn like the folllowing:

```py
dataset = dataset.repeat()# don't specify any number in the repeat()
```

Hope this will help you.